# GEOS support not enable - Java Binding GDAL

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, binding

Estou tentando criar um método que calcula intersecção utilizando a lib GDAL, porém ao chamar o método intersection tenho o retorno null com a seguinte mensagem no console: GEOS support not enable.

Estou em um ambiente Linux/Ubuntu com eclipse.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema desinstalando a lib GDAL e reinstalando na ordem GEOS e depois GDAL, passando como parâmetro o argumento --with-geos=yes ao chamar o sh configure.

Comment: Oi Leandro, seja bem vindo. 
Você poderia responder sua própria pergunta com a sua solução, assim facilitaria muito quando alguém tivesse o mesmo problema que você teve

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho Publiquei a resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema desinstalando a lib GDAL e reinstalando ela após instalar o [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos). Antes de fazer o make na lib do GDAL não esqueça de digitar o seguinte comando: `./configure --with-geos=yes`. Isso solucionou o meu problema!